# How to call a service from module in a new created layer in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I have three modules: module-a, module-b, module-c. Module-a and module-b are in boot layer. Layer for module-c I create myself.

Module-a has one interface `com.mod-a.Service` and in its module-info I have:

```
module module-a {
    exports com.mod-a;
}
```

Module-c implements `com.mod-a.Service` and in its module-info I have:

```
module module-c {
    requires module-a;
    provides com.mod-a.Service with com.mod-c.ServiceImpl;
}
```

Module-b creates new layer with module-c, and calls module-c service. In its module-info I have:

```
module module-b {
    requires module-a;
    requires java.management;
    requires slf4j.api;
    uses com.mod-a.Service;
}
```

In module-b I create new layer with module-c this way:

```
ModuleFinder finder = ModuleFinder.of(moduleCPath);
ModuleLayer parent = ModuleLayer.boot();
Configuration cf = parent.configuration().resolve(finder, ModuleFinder.of(), Set.of("module-c"));
ClassLoader scl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
ModuleLayer layer = parent.defineModulesWithOneLoader(cf, scl);
//the following line prints "module-c"
layer.modules().stream().map(Module::getName).forEach(System.out::println);
```

However, after creating layer I can't in module-b call Service of module-c. The following code:

```
Iterable<Service> it = ServiceLoader.load(Service.class);
System.out.println("LINE 1");
for (Service service : it) {
     System.out.println("Service was called");
     service.doIt();
}
System.out.println("LINE 2");
```

outputs:

```
LINE 1
LINE 2
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `module module-b {
    requires module-c;` ?

Comment: @nullpointer No. Module-b must not know about implementations of `com.mod-a.Service`. Besides, module-c is in new layer but not in boot layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceLoader.load(Class) uses the TCCL as the starting point to locate service providers for the service whereas your example should use the child layer or alternative the class loader of any class loader defining modules in the layer. So if you change the example to `ServiceLoader.load(layer, Service.class)` then it should work as you expect.

Separately, you've used `resolve` and specified the service provider module as the root module to resolve. Nothing wrong with that but an alternative would have been to use `resolveAndBind` and not specify any root modules. The `uses com.mod-a.Service` in module-b will ensure that modules that `provides com.mod-a.Service` will be resolved.

Comment: A small doubt @Alan, I was trying out the same with another overloaded method [`load​(Class<S> service, ClassLoader loader)`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#load-java.lang.Class-java.lang.ClassLoader-) using the params from the OP's code. And as the docs suggests it should have tried to locate providers from unnamed and named modules both. But I was unable to find the provider in that case either. Why could that be the case?

Comment: I've checked `resolveAndBind` has the same signature. Can you say how it is possible not to define root modules?

Comment: resolveAndBind will recursively enumerate the service dependences, resolve does not do this. So in your example, the `uses com.mod-a.Service` in a module in the parent configuration will ensure that all observable modules (the modules that your ModuleFinder can find) that `provides com.mod-a.Service` are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of your issue is that the

```
ServiceLoader.load(Service.class)
```

which is an alternate of

```
ServiceLoader.load(Service.class, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
```

doesn't end up finding any service provider for the `Service`.

One way in which I was able to fix that was to open the package of the service provider to the module which owns the service, as :

```
module module-c {
    requires module-a;
    provides com.mod-a.Service with com.mod-c.ServiceImpl;
    opens com.mod-c to module-a;
}
```

Also, would suggest going through the [`ServiceLoader`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) on how to deploy service providers ***as module*** and ***on the classpath***.